# Java Android PDF (Bitmap) is not diplayed at full size

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to show a PDF File in my App but when I show the file, it is not shown at full size, it only covers about 1/4 of the screen.

Here is my code:

```
public void render() {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        final ImageView pdfView = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        pdfView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int width = pdfView.getWidth();
                    int height = pdfView.getHeight();

                    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
                    System.out.printf("Filename: " + pdfFile.getName());
                    PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(pdfFile, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY));

                    if (currentPage < 0) {
                        currentPage = 0;
                    } else if (currentPage > renderer.getPageCount()) {
                        currentPage = renderer.getPageCount() - 1;
                    }

                    Matrix m = pdfView.getImageMatrix();
                    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
                    renderer.openPage(currentPage).render(bitmap, rect, m, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
                    pdfView.setImageMatrix(m);
                    pdfView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    pdfView.invalidate();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I log the width and the height I get the results: 1440 / 1944

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting it as page width and height. Use below code and check

```
 PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY));
                PdfRenderer.Page page = renderer.openPage(0);
                int pageWidth = page.getWidth();
                int pageHeight = page.getHeight();
                float scale = Math.min((float) REQ_WIDTH / pageWidth, (float) REQ_HEIGHT / pageHeight);
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) (pageWidth * scale), (int) (pageHeight * scale), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                page.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Thank you it is now displaying the file in the correct way.